# How to pass parameters to R plumber's unboxedJSON serializer?

Tags: r, plumber

How do you pass parameters to the R `plumber` package's `unboxedJSON` serializer? My ultimate goal is to pass these parameters to the underlying `jsonlite::toJSON()`. Based on https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/pull/356/, I thought the following would work to avoid dropping `col2` below and filling it with `null`:

```
library(plumber)

#* @serializer unboxedJSON list(na = "null")
#* @get /
function() {
  data.frame(col1 = 1, col2 = NA)
}
```

However, when starting the API it gives the error

```
Error in (function ()  : unused argument (na = "null")
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, also when changing `unboxedJSON` with `json` (following https://community.rstudio.com/t/modifying-plumber-json-response/60065/2).